# Not able to set inital height to TextInput component based on the content in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput, react-native-text

I am having a TextInput component as shown below

```
   <TextInput
      defaultValue={inputDescription}
      multiline={true}
      onChangeText={e => setInputDescription(e)}
      style={[Style.descriptionInput, { height: descriptionHeight }]}
      onContentSizeChange={e =>
        setDescriptionHeight(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)
      }
      placeholder={'Take a note'}
      placeholderTextColor={'black'}
    />
```

With the `onContentSizeChange` prop, I'm getting the current height and passing that to styles in order to grow the TextInput component size

This works when I'm changing the content. But when I pass some data to the `defaultValue` prop then the component doesn't update the height (most of the time).

I want TextInput to also update the height when the initial data is passed to the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by removing the inital value given to `descriptionHeight` variable.